# Traefik Configuration Example Mixing Let's Encrypt and Purchased Certs

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, traefik

With Traefik, I would like to use Let's Encrypt for only some new specific front end host rules since I'm already using purchased cert(s) for some existing front end host rules. Here is my existing working example traefik.toml without a Let's Encrypt [acme] configuration :

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "/etc/traefik/certs/myhost.tld.crt"
      keyFile = "/etc/traefik/certs/myhost.tld.key"
```

From what I've read [here](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/docker-and-lets-encrypt/) OnHostRule = true applies to all host rules.

Is there an example Traefik configuration that shows how to use Let's Encrypt for specific hosts and not for hosts using already purchased certs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTTPS with SNI (Server Name Indication) to assign specific SSL certificate to a specific domain or subdomain.

You can find an example of HTTPS + SNI configuration from their official documentation link below.

https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/examples/#http-https-with-sni

**EDIT 1:**

> Is there an example Traefik configuration that shows how to use Let's Encrypt for specific hosts and not for hosts using already purchased certs?

You can try the example in [this section](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/examples/#onhostrule-option-and-provided-certificates-with-http-challenge) of the official document. It says that it'll generate let's encrypt certificates only for the domains that cannot be checked by the provided certificates.

You can also refer to [this link](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#configuration) to know the explanation for each configuration item of the ACME let's encrypt configuration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm already using  HTTPS with SNI for my purchased cert as shown in my example. My question is how do I configure the [acme] section to use Let's Encrypt for other host.tld's

Comment: Can you try the example in [this section](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/examples/#onhostrule-option-and-provided-certificates-with-http-challenge) of the official document? It says that it'll generate let's encrypt certificates only for the domains that cannot be checked by the provided certificates.

Comment: Okay, that looks promising. Before I try it I need to understand what this caServer path is for and what I need to do for this on my server if anything: caServer = "http://172.18.0.1:4000/directory"

Comment: According to the example in [this link](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#caserver), `caServer` seems to be the Certificate authority server to use. I'd suggest you to leave it commented which will make traefik to use default let's encrypt ca server which is production ca server.

Comment: You can also refer to [this link](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#configuration) to know the explanation for each let's encrypt configuration item.

Comment: Thanks for your help @bharath - I got it working using the example linked in your second comment: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/examples/#onhostrule-option-and-provided-certificates-with-http-challenge

Comment: You're welcome @Jim Frenette. I'll update the answer with the links I provided in the comments so that it'll make more sense and answer the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Say your dir and file structure are like below.

```
 traefik
 |-ssl
   |-ca.key
   |-ca_chain.crt
 |-traefik.toml
 |-acme.json
```

Update your traefik.toml

```
#traefik.toml

debug = true

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

# Force HTTPS
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
     [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "/etc/traefik/ssl/ca_chain.crt"
      keyFile = "/etc/traefik/ssl/ca.key"


# Let's encrypt configuration
[acme]
email = "email@domain.com" #any email id will work
storage="/etc/traefik/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging=true
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
```

Create acme.json file

```
touch ./traefik/acme.json
chmod 600 .traefik/acme.json
```

Create container using below command:

```
docker run --network=traefik-network -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $PWD/traefik:/etc/traefik --name=traefik traefik:latest --api --docker
```